# Excel VBA - XML Not Consistently Scraping Data Into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use VBA and XML Library to loop through a set webpages (targets) that utilize the same HTML structure and scrape off some data.

When I run my code for just a few targets, it pulls the data in successfully.  But when I expand the number of targets to 10, 20, 50, etc. it begins to pull in the data inconsistently.  Sometimes it will pull in half of the data from the targets, other times it will just pull in a few targets' data.

I am decent at Excel and VBA, but am by no means a professional.  I am not sure if:

1. the macro is not pausing to let the web page data load (I put a do while loop in and also have the `XMLPage.Open` set to `False` to make it an asynchronous call), or,
2. an object needs to be destroyed at the end of each loop, or,
3. it is something entirely different.

---

**VBA:**

```
Sub GetData()
    'Activate Microsoft Internet Controls Library
    'Activate Microsoft XML, v6.0 Library
    'Activate Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim Target As String
    Dim URL As String
    Dim Elems As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Elem As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Determine Last Row
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Sheets("Home").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Start Loop Through Targets
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    For x = 2 To LR
    
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Setup Target Specifics
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Target = Cells(x, 1)
        URL = "WEBSITE/" & Target
    
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Navigate to URL Via XML
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        XMLPage.Open "GET", URL, False
        XMLPage.send
    
        Do While XMLPage.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop
    
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Create a List of Elements based on Class Name - Should Only be One Element - Then Loop Through Elements & Return Value
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Set Elems = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("Amount")
        For Each Elem In Elems
            Cells(x, 2) = Elem.innerText
        Next Elem

    Next x

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Messagebox of Completion
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    MsgBox ("Macro Complete")

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance provided.

Chris

Comment: FYI, unless `Elems` is always length 1 then you are overwriting the same cell each loop of `Elem in Elems` as `x` increments in the outer loop. If it is always a single node then remove that inner loop and use `Activesheet.Cells(x, 2) = HTMLDoc.querySelector(".Amount").innerText`. Though you should use explicit sheet references throughout and avoid `.Select` and implicit sheet references.

Comment: Hi, yes Elem is always 1 (tried to indicate that in my code notes).  I didn't know about queryselector, so I am going to try to use that.  I still have my problem with not all of the values consistently populating though.

Comment: Have you looked to see if the data you want is served by a public API?

Comment: Yes, I have.  There use to be API, but they turned it off.